# c# to vb.net code conversion(AND operation)

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do I write the following c# code line in vb.net

```
trig = 83886080 & 0x0007ffff;

i tried

trig= 83886080 AND 0x0007ffff
```

but it gives me the error on `0x0007ffff`

is there another way of writing this ?

Comment: Change `0x0007ffff` to `&H0007ffff`

Comment: I recommend you for future problems trying first this [converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)